# how to give access permission to the files on godaddy server web hosting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, hosting

I am hosting my .net webservice on godaddy server. I have given read/write rights to folders.
But it doesnt provide giveing rights to any file.

So when i am trying to upload any file from my webservice to the server, it gives me an error

```
"You dont have rights to access D:\Hosting\957031\html "
```

What can be the problem ?

How can i solve it ?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the IIS User does not have enough permission to create / write files in html folder. You should contact your hosting provider for this.

Comment: thanks for reply. Ya you are right. We dont have rights to create/write files in html folder. I have solved my problem by creating new folder in html folder and than giveing the access rights to that new created folder. And It works fine. Now i can upload my files in that folder. : )